# reverse one axis in ternary graph rstudio

Tags: r, ternary

I am trying to plot a ternary graph with ggtern. I just need to manually invert the gradation of an axis and it seems impossible to do with this package. The one (and only one) I would like to invert the order of values is the one corresponding to my "A" data and so it's the scale_T_continuous. If it is impossible to do with ggtern please advise me other packages that allow more customization of a ternary graph.

here is my code:

```
 ggtern(all_class, aes(A, B, C)) +
    geom_point() + 
    labs(title = "Ternary Plot Title", x = "A Label", y = "B Label", z = "C Label") +
    scale_T_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1), labels = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
    scale_L_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1), labels = seq(0, 1, 0.1)) +
    scale_R_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1), labels = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible by pasting your data into the question with `dput(all_class)`. This makes it easier for others to copy the data to test and verify solutions. Non base R packages should be included in the question. [Guidance for making a reproducible example] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)